# jQuery: check data-filter and replace spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm trying to get jQuery to check all data-filter inside this list, in case it finds a space between word,  it should be replaced with ", ." (I need those to be classes).

This is what I tried, but when I check the console, it says "replace is not a function".

HTML

```
<ul class="filter-list" data-option-key="filter">
    <li>
        <a data-filter=".class one" class="" href="#filter">class one</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="" href="#filter" data-filter=".class two">class two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="" href="#filter" data-filter=".class three">class three</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('.filter-list a[data-filter]').each(function () {
    $(this).replace(/\s/g,", .");
});
```

Basically, when jQuery finds ".class three" , it should replace it with ".class .three" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) to do it

```
$('.filter-list a[data-filter]').attr('data-filter', function (i, attr) {
    return attr.replace(/\s+/g, ", .");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZaJ2s/)

Your code fails because inside `each()` handler, `this` refers to the dom element and `$(ths)` returns a jQuery object which does not have the replace method

Comment: I understand now, thank you for your answer. The code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
$('.filter-list a[data-filter]').each(function () {
  $(this).replace(/\s/g,", .");
});
```

`$(this)` is a DOM element. You can get the text by `$(this).text()`. So your code can be something like:

```
$('.filter-list a[data-filter]').each(function () {
  $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\s/g,", ."));
});
```